# Can somebody explain this RegEx to me?

Tags: javascript, regex

I see this line of code and the regular expression just panics me...

```
quickExpr = /^(?:[^#<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]*)$)/
```

Can someone please explain **little by little** what it does?
Thanks,G

Comment: Can't you break the regex up yourself and Google each component? It's pretty simple.

Comment: I started to, but `[\w\W]` doesn't make sense to me. Curious to see what answers you get.

Comment: @Blender you are right.Actually I am reading up about it on MDN.

Comment: @GGG: That's any word character or non word character. In other words, any character. I've more often seen it as `\s\S`

Comment: Looks to me like it's matching stuff inside `<>` and stuff after # (maybe # is a comment indicator?)

Comment: @amnotiam how does it differ from `.`?

Comment: @GGG: `.` doesn't match line breaks.

Comment: @amnotiam aha, thanks... but without the `/m` modifier, that doesn't seem useful...

Comment: @amnotiam so you mean `\s\S` and `\w\W` means the same?

Comment: @Gnijuohz "whitespace or not whitespace" is the same as "word character or not word character" in that they both mean "match anything." What I was missing was the difference between the normal "match anything" operator (`.`) and the use of `[\w\W]` to match anything. Which, in this context, I still don't understand if it's only about line breaks (no `/m` modifier).

Comment: @GGG: It's useful if you don't want a line break to prevent the pattern from gobbling characters. The `m` alters the regex so that each line is effectively evaluated as a separate string *(with respect to `^` and `$`)*, so a line break becomes irrelevant, and allows the `.` to suffice.

Comment: @amnotiam of course, thank you, I was having a moment there... I was thinking of JS regex as working like sed WRT multiple lines =/

Comment: /./ leaves out some really obscure whitespace characters that \w\W wouldn't. I forget which ones but I think they used to do things like signify the 'ding' on old teletype machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I can extract:

- `^` beginning of string.
- `(?:` non-matching group.
- `[^#<]*` any number of consecutive characters that aren't `#` or `<`.
- `(<[\w\W]+>)` a group that matches strings like `<anything_goes_here>`.
- `[^>]*` any number of characters in sequence that aren't a `>`.

The part after the `|` denotes a second regex to try if the first one fails. That one is `#([\w\-]*)`:

- `#` matches the `#` character. Not that complex.
- `([\w\-]*)` is a group that matches any number of word characters or dashes. Basically `Things-of-this-form`
- `$` marks the end of the regex.

I'm no regex pro, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am not used to two Special characters appear at the same time.Like `\w\W`,shouldn't it first match a word character then non-word character(as is suggested by the first answer) instead of match anything?Same problem with `\w\-`.

Comment: When things are in `[]` brackets, they aren't in any particular order. The `[]` brackets denote character sets, which are used to include/exclude stuff from regexes (like `[a-z]+` matches the same thing as `[zyxvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba]+)`

Comment: @Gnijuohz the square brackets `[...]` mean match any one of the things inside. `\w\W` would mean match one and then the other, `[\w\W]` means match either one.

Comment: @GGG I think you helped me clear a lot of things up.I really appreciate that!

Comment: `\w` is all word characters. `\W` is all non-word characters. You're adding both together, so you get `.`.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:[^#<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]*)$)

Assert position at the start of the string «^»
Match the regular expression below «(?:[^#<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]*)$)»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[^#<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$»
      Match a single character NOT present in the list "#<" «[^#<]*»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(<[\w\W]+>)»
         Match the character "<" literally «<»
         Match a single character present in the list below «[\w\W]+»
            Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
            Match a single character that is a "word character" (letters, digits, etc.) «\w»
            Match a single character that is a "non-word character" «\W»
         Match the character ">" literally «>»
      Match any character that is not a ">" «[^>]*»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
      Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «#([\w\-]*)$»
      Match the character "#" literally «#»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([\w\-]*)»
         Match a single character present in the list below «[\w\-]*»
            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
            Match a single character that is a "word character" (letters, digits, etc.) «\w»
            A - character «\-»
      Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»


Created with RegexBuddy
```

Comment: So, where's your explanation?

Comment: It's telling you, bit by bit what the regex does. It's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: If you don't understand it just grab RegexBuddy, it will explain it to you with colours and selections and indicators and such. If you still don't understand it than you should really start learning about regexes, they're not that simple for unexperienced users

Comment: @david I don't want to be rude,but someone seems to be reading for me.